# BigQuery - Move from a synchronous job to an asynchronous job

Tags: google-bigquery

After a certain time, I would like to make a synchronous job (launched with `jobs.query`)  asynchronous (as if it were launched with `jobs.insert`) but I don't want to launch a new job. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `jobs.query` here I'm assuming you're referring [bigquery rest api](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query).
One approach to make your query job async, referring to their [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query), is as below:

1. specify a minimum `timeoutMs` property in [QueryRequest](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#queryrequest) while preparing query `POST` request, so that you request does not wait till query finishes i.e. become synchronous
2. after you `POST`ing the query, past minimum timeout value, you'll receive [response](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#response-body) with a [JobReference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/JobReference) attribute
3. use the `jobId` from [JobReference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/JobReference) to track/poll status of your query at later time asynchronously

And if you refer to not-rest api approaches such as for Java or Python languages, they have out-of-the-box api specifically to execute the query synchronously or asynchronously.